# Random graph is simple cycle or tree

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

Consider an undirected random graph $G$ of $n$ vertices. The probability that there is an edge between a pair of vertices is $p$.

What is the probability that $G$ is simple cycle of $n$ vertices or tree of $n$ vertices?

My solution:

Number of simple cycles is $\frac{(n - 1)!}{2}$ and number of trees is $n^{n - 2}$.

For every simple cycle prolability is $p^{n - 1}$ $(1 - p)^{(\frac{n}{2}) - n + 1}$ and for every tree probability is $p^{n - 1}$ $(1 - p)^{(\frac{n}{2}) - n + 1}$.

Answer is $(\frac{(n - 1)!}{2} + n^{n - 2}) p^{n - 1} (1 - p)^{(\frac{n}{2}) - n + 1}$.

Is my answer true?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: @MTurgeon, i add my proof.

Is proof correct?

Comment: Not quite. How many edges in a complete graph? How many edges to make a simple cycle? From your (incomplete) proof, it seems you made a mistake in computing these two quantities.

Comment: @MTurgeon, $(\frac{n + 1}{2}) = \frac{n (n + 1)}{2}$ in complete graph, $n$ in simple cycle and answer is $p^{n - 1} (1 - p)^ {\frac{n (n + 1)}{2} - n } (p  \frac{(n - 1)!}{2} + (1 - p) n^{n - 2})$.

Is it true?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. But I don't know why you write $$\frac{n+1}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2},$$ as it is clearly false... Perhaps you meant to use the choose notation?

Comment: Oh, it is binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the event that the random graph is a tree, and let $C$ be the event that it is a simple cycle. We are interested in
$$P(T\mbox{ or }C) = P(T) + P(C) - P(T\mbox{ and }C) = P(T) + P(C).$$
In a complete graph there are ${n\choose 2}$ edges, and therefore for a fixed graph $G$ with $m$ edges on $n$ vertices, a random graph will be equal to $G$ with probability
$$p^m(1-p)^{{n\choose 2}-m}.$$

If $t$ and $c$ are the number of trees and cycles on $n$ vertices, respectively, and $m_t$ and $m_c$ the number of edges in a tree and cycle, respectively, you have
$$P(T) = t\cdot p^{m_t}(1-p)^{{n\choose 2}-m_t},\qquad P(C) = c\cdot p^{m_c}(1-p)^{{n\choose 2}-m_c}.$$

I think you can pick it up from here...